# Using extension method with LinQPad

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linqpad

I have a project that uses Entity Framework, code first. I would like to use LINQPad to seed my database.

To seed a database during the migration operation with Entity Framework I use the `AddOrUpdate()` extension method:

```
context.Rule.AddOrUpdate(
    y => y.Id,
    new Rule() { Id = Guid.Parse("b9b4fc65-fd0b-4f7f-aa27-3147c7665d27"), ... },
    new Rule() { Id = Guid.Parse("66d27186-8be4-4ce2-8a74-737576e7157b"), ... }
);
```

When I try to do the same with LINQPad I get an error:

```
Rules.AddOrUpdate(
    y => y.Id,
    new Rules() { Id = Guid.Parse("b9b4fc65-fd0b-4f7f-aa27-3147c7665d27"),  ... },
    new Rules() { Id = Guid.Parse("66d27186-8be4-4ce2-8a74-737576e7157b"), ... }
);
```

I get this error:

> CS1929 'Table' does not contain a definition for 'AddOrUpdate' and the best extension method overload 'DbSetMigrationsExtensions.AddOrUpdate(IDbSet, params Rules[])' requires a receiver of type 'IDbSet'

Why doesn't LINQPad see this extension method? I have already added the NuGet reference to EntityFramework, and added all namespace in the NuGet package manager and namespace import of LINQPad.

I tried to write the same code like this:

```
System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbSetMigrationsExtensions.AddOrUpdate(
        Rules as System.Data.Entity.IDbSet<Rules>,
        y => y.Id,
        new Rules() { Id = Guid.Parse("b9b4fc65-fd0b-4f7f-aa27-3147c7665d27"), ... },
        new Rules() { Id = Guid.Parse("66d27186-8be4-4ce2-8a74-737576e7157b"), ... }
);
```

But I get this error:

> CS0039 Cannot convert type 'System.Data.Linq.Table<LINQPad.User.Rules>' to 'System.Data.Entity.IDbSet<LINQPad.User.Rules>' via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion

So I guess the extension method is not working because the type of my `Rules` object is not correct. It seems LINQPad uses its own object type and I cannot convert it.

Comment: On your connection, are you using the `Build data context automatically` option rather than `Use a  typed data context from your own assembly` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, you should add `System.Data.Entity.Migrations` to the LINQPad query's namespace imports (press F4).

Next, you are deluded by the `AddOrUpdate` method's signature. The first parameter is `IDbSet<TEntity>`, but that parameter is supplied automatically when you use it as extension method. In `context.Rule.AddOrUpdate`, it's `context.Rule`.

If you don't have `IDbSet<TEntity>`, then you probably didn't connect to an EF6 DbContext.

When using it in a regular static method call (just for academic purposes), it should be

```
DbSetMigrationsExtensions.AddOrUpdate(context.Rule, y => y.Id, rules);
```

(where `rules`, of course, is your collection of rules).

By the way, you could also use `context.Rule.AddOrUpdate(rules)` because EF used the primary key by default.